# Error message in summary because of quotation mark

Tags: r, dataframe

This my code:

```
 summary(data$diff`GBP/EUR`)
```

This is the error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "summary(data$diff`GBP/EUR`"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `[[`

```
summary(data[["diff`GBP/EUR`"]])
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  1       2       3       3       4       5
```

---

Or wrap the whole string within quotes while using `$`

```
summary(data$"diff`GBP/EUR`")
#  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 1       2       3       3       4       5
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame("diff`GBP/EUR`" = 1:5, check.names = FALSE)
```